# Beginner-Java-DiceRoll-Keystroke to keep rolling

Tags: java

Still very new to coding.  Just messing around with making a dice roll game and was wondering how I could keep the program running and have the user hit (Enter)or any other key for that matter, to keep rolling.  Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random generator = new Random();
        int diceSum;
        int roll1;
        int roll2;

        roll1 = generator.nextInt(7);
        roll2 = generator.nextInt(7);

        diceSum = roll1 + roll2;
        System.out.println("You rolled a: " + diceSum);

    }

}
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java

Comment: You'll need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop (it would be up to you whether or not with an end condition).This  hit feature could be accomplished with a line reader command of some kind after the result printing. For instance:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
reader.readLine();
```